# rake test - self.table_name not recognized

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, ruby-on-rails-3, rake

I have a strange error. When I try to run a unit test, it gives me the following error:

```
test_the_truth(UpdateMainTest):
 ActiveRecord::StatementInvalid: Could not find table 'blacklists'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:472:in `table_structure'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/sqlite_adapter.rb:346:in `columns'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:660:in `column_names'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:652:in `timestamp_column_names'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:585:in `block in table_rows'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:579:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:579:in `map'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:579:in `table_rows'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:494:in `block (3 levels) in create_fixtures'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:492:in `each'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:492:in `block (2 levels) in create_fixtures'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/database_statements.rb:192:in `transaction'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:491:in `block in create_fixtures'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract_adapter.rb:168:in `disable_referential_integrity'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:476:in `create_fixtures'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:895:in `load_fixtures'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activerecord-3.2.13/lib/active_record/fixtures.rb:849:in `setup_fixtures'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:407:in `_run__379848442555604621__setup__3487204981098397389__callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:405:in `__run_callback'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:385:in `_run_setup_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:81:in `run_callbacks'
/var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/activesupport-3.2.13/lib/active_support/testing/setup_and_teardown.rb:35:in `run'
```

This is my Blacklist model:

```
class Blacklist < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :abbreviation, :name
  self.table_name = "blacklist"
  validates :abbreviation, :presence => :true, :uniqueness => :true
  validates :name, :presence => :true
end
```

The schema also correctly lists the table:

```
  create_table "blacklist", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "abbreviation"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

I ran rake db:test:prepare more than once, but the error stays.
When I use the rails console I can create Blacklist objects without an error.
Any idea what I could do?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all of your help.

I couldn't really trace the root of the problem, but when I 
commented out the line in the test_helper.rb that loads all the fixtures, the error didn't come up again.

Answer (score 0):

Use the symbol with pluralize form, table name should be plural:

```
self.table_name = :blacklists
```

create table name with plural form :

```
create_table "blacklists", :force => true do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.string   "abbreviation"
    t.datetime "created_at",   :null => false
    t.datetime "updated_at",   :null => false
  end
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but I especially specified the self.table_name to not have to use the name "blacklists". If there is a function to name the table in a non-standard way, shouldn't it be able to function properly?

Comment: use self.class.table_name. It might work. and use it above attr_accessible.

Comment: Tried both. self.class.table_name gives the error that the method table_name is not available in Class:Class and putting it before attr_accessible does not make a change either.

Answer (score 0):

If is only happening with your unit tests, maybe the test db is outdated. You should try to rebuild it `rake db:migrate db:test:clone`